# Java programming, how to break from an infinite loop?

Tags: java, cycle

i have this programm for my studies, but i can't find how to end this cycle. Can you help me? I can't really find how to quit this cycle, i'm not must use while function and not allowed to use break function

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Ld2141reb130 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        double g=9.81, a=40;
        a = Math.toRadians(a);
        double t, x = 0, y=0, v0;
        boolean hitTarget=false;
        String s;
        System.out.println("Artūrs Škutāns IRDBF1 000RDB111");
        try {
            System.out.print("v0=");
            s = br.readLine();
            v0 = Double.parseDouble(s);
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("input-output error");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("t  \t  x \t  y");
        t = 0.05;
        while (hitTarget=true)  {
            x = v0*t*Math.cos(a);
            y = v0*t* Math.sin(a) - (g*t*t)/2;;
            System.out.printf("%3.2f\t%7.3f\t%7.3f\n", t, x, y);
            if (x>=15 && x<=18 && y<=6 && y>4) {
                hitTarget = true;
            }
            t += 0.05;
        } 
        while ( y>=0 || x>=10 && y>=4 );
        if (hitTarget)
            System.out.println("the target was destroyed");
        else
            System.out.println("shot off the target");
    }
}
```

Comment: while (hitTarget=true)  { You probably want while (hitTarget==true) (double equals)

Comment: What is this `while ( y>=0 || x>=10 && y>=4 );` supposed to be doing?

Comment: [Gotcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha_(programming))

Comment: I think you actually want `while (!hitTarget)` i.e. loop until the target is hit. The loop right afterwards: `while ( y>=0 || x>=10 && y>=4 );`, I have no idea what you're trying to do with that.

Comment: I have this task:
http://prntscr.com/8ry1bg
So i want to show tre trajectory of a shot with given values of speed(user input v0) and an angle in which shot is fired (a) also cycle should end if hitTarget hits green or red fields, And print different messages if target(red field) is hit or it missed (green field). I copied most of the code from an example given, but i'm not good at Java programming and can't explain everything it shows. Thanks for help btw! But now there is no output numbers :(

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with

```
while (hitTarget=true)  {
```

this assigns hitTarget to true and then checks if it is true (which is is)

Change to

```
while (hitTarget==true)  {
```

or even better

```
while (hitTarget)  {
```

But since you start with hitTarget as false you probably want to change your declaration of hitTarget to true or change your loop to a do while instead to get at least one execution and also have some condition where hotTarget will be set to false.

Then you have an empty loop

```
while ( y>=0 || x>=10 && y>=4 );
```

that will be an infinite loop if you ever enter it (since it doesn't change any state)

Perhaps you wanted something like

```
do {
    x = v0*t*Math.cos(a);
    y = v0*t* Math.sin(a) - (g*t*t)/2;;
    System.out.printf("%3.2f\t%7.3f\t%7.3f\n", t, x, y);
    if (x>=15 && x<=18 && y<=6 && y>4) {
        hitTarget = true;
    }
    t += 0.05;
} while (hitTarget || y>=0 || x>=10 && y>=4 );
```

Comment: Even then, `hitTarget` never gets set to false inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Two obvious mistakes in there:

a) write `while (hitTarget)` or `while (hitTarget == true)`
(what you have in your code will **assign** the value true to hitTarget; directly translating your code into `while(true)`)

On top of that:

b) you need something inside your loop that changes the value of `hitTarget` to false

In other words: you instruct your loop to run forever; and then you are wondering why it never stops?

Finally: consider breaking your code into more smaller methods. Would make it much easier to read and understand.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! i'm really new to Java and programming at all, so i vahe struggle with this. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I bet, that you want to end loop when hitTarget is set to true. To end that loop you must check if `hitTarget != false`:

`while (hitTarget != false)`

or simply:

`while (!hitTarget)`